# Contraseña incorrecta Python con MySQL

Tags: php, python, mysql, base-de-datos, xampp

He estado haciendo una pagina que tome datos para el registro de un usuario y despues puedan iniciar sesion, sin embargo me di cuenta hace poco que no logro iniciar sesion, en cualquier momento me dice la advertencia de que la contraseña es incorrecta, a pesar de que estoy seguro de que la contraseña que estoy introduciendo es la correcta. Antes funcionaba pero ya no. Soy nuevo en esto

Petfarm.py:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for,request,redirect,flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL, MySQLdb
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, logout_user
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from config import config
from models.ModelUser import ModelUser
from models.entities.User import User
from flask_mail import Mail,Message

petfarmApp = Flask(__name__)
db = MySQL(petfarmApp)
LMpetfarmApp = LoginManager(petfarmApp)
mail = Mail(petfarmApp)

petfarmApp.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'hector.murguia1702@gmail.com'
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'ipcw wcom ubsv nfla'
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'hector.murguia1702@gmail.com'
petfarmApp.config['MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS'] = True

@LMpetfarmApp.user_loader
def Cargadoru(id):
    return ModelUser.get_by_id(db, id)

@petfarmApp.route('/')
def home():
   SelProductos = db.connection.cursor()
   SelProductos.execute("SELECT * FROM registro")
   p = SelProductos.fetchall()
   return render_template('home.html', Productos = p)

@petfarmApp.route('/signin', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nombreu = request.form['nombreu']
        correou = request.form['correou']
        claveu = request.form['claveu']
        claveCifrada = generate_password_hash(claveu)
        regUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
        regUsuario.execute("INSERT INTO usuario (nombreu, correou, claveu) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(nombreu,correou,claveCifrada))
        db.connection.commit()
        msg = Message(subject='PetFarm', recipients=[correou])
        msg.html = render_template('user_mail.html', nombrem = nombreu)
        mail.send(msg)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    else:
        return render_template('signin.html')
    
@petfarmApp.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario = User(0,None,request.form['correou'],request.form['claveu'],None)
        usuarioAut= ModelUser.login(db,usuario)
        if usuarioAut is not None:
            login_user(usuarioAut)
            if usuarioAut.claveu:
                if usuarioAut.perfilu == 'A':
                    return render_template('admin.html')
                else:
                    SelProductos = db.connection.cursor()
                    SelProductos.execute("SELECT * FROM productos")
                    p = SelProductos.fetchall()
                    return render_template('usuario.html',productos = p)
            else:
                flash('Contraseña Incorrecta')
            return redirect(request.url)
        else:
            flash('Usuario Inexistente')
        return redirect(request.url)
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@petfarmApp.route('/sUsuario', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sUsuario():
    SelUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
    SelUsuario.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario")
    u = SelUsuario.fetchall()
    return render_template('profiles.html', usuario = u)

@petfarmApp.route('/logout', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@petfarmApp.route('/iUsuario',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def iUsuario():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nombreu = request.form['nombreu']
        correou = request.form['correou']
        claveu = request.form['claveu']
        claveCifrada = generate_password_hash(claveu)
        perfilu = request.form['perfilu']
        regUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
        regUsuario.execute("INSERT INTO usuario (nombreu, correou, claveu, perfilu) VALUES (%s,%s,%s.%s)",(nombreu,correou,claveCifrada,perfilu))
        db.connection.commit()
        flash('Usuario Agregado')
        return redirect(url_for('sUsuario'))
    else:
        return redirect(request.url)

@petfarmApp.route('/uUsuario/<string:id>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uUsuario(id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nombreu = request.form['nombreu']
        correou = request.form['correou']
        claveu = request.form['claveu']
        claveCifrada = generate_password_hash(claveu)
        perfilu = request.form['perfilu']
        actUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
        actUsuario.execute("UPDATE usuario SET nombreu=%s, correou=%s, claveu=%s, perfilu=%s WHERE id = %s",(nombreu,correou,claveCifrada,perfilu,id))
        db.connection.commit()
        flash('Usuario Actualizado')
        return redirect(url_for('sUsuario'))
    else:
        return redirect(request.url)
    
@petfarmApp.route('/dUsuario/<string:id>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dUsuario(id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        delUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
        delUsuario.execute("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id=%s",(id,))
        db.connection.commit()
        flash('Usuario Eliminado')
        return redirect(url_for('sUsuario'))
    else:
        return redirect(request.url)

@petfarmApp.route('/sProducto', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sProducto():
    SelProducto = db.connection.cursor()
    SelProducto.execute("SELECT * FROM producto")
    p = SelProducto.fetchall()
    return render_template('productos.html', productos = p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    petfarmApp.config.from_object(config['development'])
    petfarmApp.run(debug=True,port=3300)
```

ModelUser.py:

```
from models.entities.User import User

class ModelUser:
    @classmethod
    def login (self,db,usuario):
        try:
            selUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
            selUsuario.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correou = %s", (usuario.correou,))
            u = selUsuario.fetchone()
            if u is not None:
                return User(u[0],u[1],u[2],User.validar_clave(u[3], usuario.claveu),u[4])
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
                raise Exception(ex)
    @classmethod
    def get_by_id(self,db,id):
        try:
            selUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
            selUsuario.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = %s", (id,))
            u = selUsuario.fetchone()
            if u is not None:
                return User(u[0],u[1],u[2],(u[3]),u[4])
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)
```

User.py:

```
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin):
    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, id, nombreu, correou, claveu, perfilu) -> None:
        self.id             = id
        self.nombreu        = nombreu
        self.correou        = correou
        self.claveu         = claveu
        self.perfilu        = perfilu

    @classmethod
    def validar_clave(self, claveCifrada, claveu):
        return check_password_hash(claveCifrada, claveu)
```

Login.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block titulo %} Iniciar sesion {% endblock %}
{% block contenido %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">PetFarm</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/signin"></i>Registrate</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login"></i>Iniciar Sesion</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              {% with mensajes = get_flashed_messages() %}
              {% if mensajes%}
              <ul class=flashes>
                {% for msj in mensajes %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation"></i> {{ msj }}
                </div>
                  <li>{{ msj }}</li>
                   {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              {% endif %}
            {% endwith %} 
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="email" name="correou" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" placeholder="Correo">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3 row">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="password" name="claveu" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Signin.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block titulo %} Registrate {% endblock %}
{% block contenido %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa-solid fa-paw"></i></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/signin"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
    <form action="/signin" method="post" class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="correou" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="claveu" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label for="inputName" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombreu" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nombre completo">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrarse</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[eEsta es la base de Datos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5axl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhklo.png)

Ya revise que realmente las contraseñas coincidan he comparado otros proyectos, incluso lo intente con la contraseña sin cifrar.

Comment: 1. Mostre el descripción de el error.
2. Remova "php", "base-de-datos" y "xampp" marcadores, estes marcadores no relacionada con tu pregunta.